# GitHub Actions Job is skipped although all needs succeeded

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

We do have a problem with a GitHub Actions job which is always skipped although all "needed" jobs did run successfully. That's the job:

```yaml
  deploy-api:
    needs: [build-test-api, terraform-apply, set-deployment-env]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/workflow-api-deploy.yml
```

To verify that all needs did pass, I have added another job for debugging and printed the result of the needed jobs.

```yaml
  debug-deploy-api:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build-test-api, terraform-apply, set-deployment-env]
    if: always() # Had to add this, otherwise it would be skipped just as "deploy-api".
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "Result of build-test-api: ${{ needs.build-test-api.result }}"
          echo "Result of terraform-apply: ${{ needs.terraform-apply.result }}"
          echo "Result of set-deployment-env: ${{ needs.set-deployment-env.result }}"
```

The output is

```bash
Result of build-test-api: success
Result of terraform-apply: success
Result of set-deployment-env: success
```

I don't understand why `deploy-api` is skipped.

### Job began to be skipped after this change

The behavior started after adding a dependency to `build-test-api`:

With this version of `build-test-api`, the deploy job did run just fine:

```yaml
  build-test-api:
    uses: # reusable WF from internal repo
    needs: set-deployment-env
```

After changing it into

```yaml
  build-test-api:
    uses: # reusable WF from internal repo
    needs: [set-deployment-env, auto-versioning]
    if: |
      always() &&
      (needs.set-deployment-env.result == 'success') &&
      (needs.auto-versioning.result == 'success' || needs.auto-versioning.result == 'skipped')
```

`deploy-api` has been skipped always. But `build-test-api` is, despite that change, still running fine and even appends the created artifact to the workflow run.

Activating runner and step debug logging did not reveal any insights on why the job is still skipped. Any ideas?

Comment: I made a test using [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester72.yml) (let me know if I missed something) and all the jobs were executed as expected without skipping any, as you can check [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3439539810). Could you check the implementation and tell me what may be different comparing to your context?

Comment: Thanks for setting up a minimal example. I have adapted to fully reflect our scenario and was able to reproduce the issue. See this [workflow run](https://github.com/Michaelvsk/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3443827588) - starting the WF with input `environment` set to `dev` let _auto-versioning_ skip but _deploy-api_ is then skipped, too.
But this [run](https://github.com/Michaelvsk/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3443855784) with `environment` = `qa`, _auto-versioning_ is running and _deploy-api_, too. @GuiFalourd

Comment: What a strange behavior! For what I understand, the `needs` field is interpreted first, and check all previous jobs dependencies as well (the whole job dependencies tree). However, it's possible to bypass the `needs` field by using the `if: always()` expression at the job level. This would explain why the `build-test-api` ran but not the `deploy-api` one.

Comment: Explaining it differently: `deploy-api` needs `build-test-api` which needs `auto-versioning`. And as `auto-versioning` didn't run with `dev`, the GitHub interpreter might consider the conditions to run the `deploy-api` job aren't met. The behavior is different for the `build-test-api` job (which also needs the `auto-versioning` job) due to the `if: always()` expression, which force the execution to happen even if the `needs` condition isn't met.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the case. For now we have separated the `auto-versioning` into a separate workflow as a temporary workaround. But that's far from ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile I did contact the GitHub Premium Support and they provided a solution:

```
deploy-api:
  if: success('build-test-api') # This line is required, if any of the previous job did not end with status 'success'.
  needs: build-test-api
  uses: ./.github/workflows/48-reusable-workflow-2.yml
```

I think I also know why: The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions) says:

> You can use the following status check functions as expressions in `if` conditionals. A default status check of `success()` is applied unless you include one of these functions.

And [definition of `success()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#success) is as follows:

> Returns `true` when none of the previous steps have failed or been canceled.

The only issue I think is, that is should be:

> Returns `true` when none of the previous steps have failed, canceled or skipped.